# Convert Dated Oracle Joins to SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey all: Here's an old query that I've been editing for speed and ease of use, and hilariously I've spent an hour reformatting this piece of the code to no avail.

```
FROM        OPEN_ORDER_DETAILS OD, BUSINESS_ENTITY BE, CONTRACT_ITEMS CI, CONTRACTS C, BUSINESS_ENTITY BE1
                    
                    WHERE       OD.SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = BE.BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID
                        AND     C.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = BE1.BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID
                        AND     (OD.CONTRACT_ID = CI.CONTRACT_ID
                            AND OD.CONTRACT_ITEM_ID = CI.CONTRACT_ITEM_ID)
                        AND     OD.CONTRACT_ID = C.CONTRACT_ID
```

AND here's what I've got, not returning same results:

```
FROM    OPEN_ORDER_DETAILS OD
            INNER JOIN BUSINESS_ENTITY BE ON OD.SHIP_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = BE.BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID
            INNER JOIN CONTRACTS C ON BE.BUSINESS_ENTITY_ID = C.BILL_TO_CUSTOMER_ID
            INNER JOIN CONTRACT_ITEMS CI ON OD.CONTRACT_ID = CI.CONTRACT_ID AND OD.CONTRACT_ITEM_ID = CI.CONTRACT_ITEM_ID
            INNER JOIN CONTRACTS C ON OD.CONTRACT_ID = C.CONTRACT_ID
```

Everything I've read says there should be Inner Joins (no plus signs), and yet I'm returning **far more** results than I should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you're missing the 2nd `BUSINESS_ENTITY` table (whose alias is `BE1`) and
- have two `CONTRACTS C` tables; that can't even run, so what you posted doesn't seem to be true

Unless I'm wrong, the "original" query rewritten would be

```
     FROM open_order_details od
     JOIN business_entity  be  ON be.business_entity_id  = od.ship_to_customer_id
     JOIN contract_items   ci  ON ci.contract_id         = od.contract_id
                              AND ci.contract_item_id    = od.contract_item_id
     JOIN contracts        c   ON c.contract_id          = od.contract_id
     JOIN business_entity  be1 ON be1.business_entity_id = c.bill_to_customer_id;
```

Comment: You were correct in the first part; the second, the contract and contract_items tables are different

Comment: They certainly are. But - review again your 2nd code. There's `CONTRACTS C` table reference in lines #3 and #5 (so I believe I'm right for both parts).

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I didn't catch on to the reference! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Developer, if you right click on your query, there is an option to convert the query from Oracle joins to ANSII joins. After clicking on that option, you are given the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
         open_order_details od
    INNER JOIN business_entity be ON od.ship_to_customer_id = be.business_entity_id
    INNER JOIN contract_items  ci ON od.contract_id = ci.contract_id
                                    AND od.contract_item_id = ci.contract_item_id
    INNER JOIN contracts       c ON od.contract_id = c.contract_id
    INNER JOIN business_entity be1 ON c.bill_to_customer_id = be1.business_entity_id
```

[image: right click menu]

Comment: You were correct! The poster before you answered it first. I wish I could mark two answers, yours is a little more in-depth.

Comment: I can't :( my reputation is too low.